# How can I get images from a retweet?

Tags: jquery, json, api, twitter

Hey guys I can get the images from a original tweet but from a retweet all I get is the text but not the images. Is there a way to get this?

```
var tweet = twt[i] //here I get the twitter posts 
console.log(tweet.text) //return the tweet text
console.log(tweet.entities.media[0].media_url) //return tweet image but only if the image is part of the original post
```

Answer (score 0):

As you will see from [the documentation on retweeting](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/id), the structure for retweets is slightly different from regular tweets.

The look something like:

`tweet
|_ retweeted_status
   |_ entities`

In your case, you will want to use something like...

`console.log(tweet.retweeted_status.entities.media[0].media_url)`